# Pandas resample function issue from minute to millisecond ersampling

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, missing-data, resampling

I am having trouble in using the pandas resample function. I have minute sampled data and I am trying to resample with 0.7 second frequency. I tried using resample with '700L' option but is not behaving as expected.
I made an example:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def convert_2_datetime(timestamp, timezoneid):
    """

    :param timestamp: UTC format in milliseconds (data.index.values)
    :param timezoneid: timezone object from CTX (for example pytz.timezone(ctx.inp.assets[0].properties['timezoneid']))
    :return: vector of datetimes
    """

    if isinstance(timestamp,int) or isinstance(timestamp,float):
        utctime = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp / 1000).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
        output = utctime.astimezone(pytz.timezone(timezoneid.zone))
    else:
        utctime = [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(i / 1000).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc) for i in timestamp]
        output = [i.astimezone(pytz.timezone(timezoneid.zone)) for i in utctime]

    return output

# minute sampled data
v1 = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
data = pd.DataFrame({'v1':np.array(v1)},index=np.arange(start=1,stop=len(v1)+1)*60000)

data['ts']= convert_2_datetime(timestamp=data.index.values,timezoneid=pytz.timezone('UTC'))
data.set_index('ts',inplace=True)
data07 = data.resample(rule='700L',closed={'right','left'}).interpolate(method='linear')
data06 = data.resample(rule='600L',closed={'right','left'}).interpolate(method='linear')
data11 = data.resample(rule='1100L',closed={'right','left'}).interpolate(method='linear')

plt.show()

data07.v1.plot(style='.',label='700 ms')
data06.v1.plot(style='.', label = '600 ms')
data11.v1.plot(style='.', label = '1500 ms')
data.v1.plot(style='x',label='original')
plt.legend()

print('Finish!')
```

The final outcome is correct if I resample with '600L' (data06 in the example); it is not correct with '700L' (data07 in the example). See next figure:

[image]

I am missing something about resample function?

Thanks a lot to everyone!

Comment: I guess it would have to do with the fact that 60 (seconds) is prime with 7, but not with 6, and so different amount of NaNs are created, and interpolated.

Comment: the behavior of the `resample` function is really unexpected here ; I guess it could be worthy of an opened github issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Workaround**

In your case, I think you should resample on a method, for example on `mean`, before you interpolate. I believe this just has to do with the output of `resample`, and the way `interpolate` reads that. As an example, the following appears to work:

```
data07 = data.resample('700L').mean().interpolate()
data06 = data.resample('600L').mean().interpolate()
data10 = data.resample('1000L').mean().interpolate()
```

This plot shows that it works:

```
data07.v1.plot(style='.',label='700 ms', alpha=0.75, ms=3,zorder=2)
data06.v1.plot(style='^',label='600 ms', alpha=0.5, zorder=1)
data10.v1.plot(style='^',label='1000 ms', alpha=0.5, zorder=0, ms=10)
data.v1.plot(style='x',label='original', ms=10)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

**Explanation (kind of...)**:

When you resample your data using any method, including `mean()`, you get `NaN`s for wherever your data was resampled:

```
>>> data.resample('700L').mean().head()
                                   v1
ts                                   
1970-01-01 00:00:59.500000+00:00  0.0
1970-01-01 00:01:00.200000+00:00  NaN
1970-01-01 00:01:00.900000+00:00  NaN
1970-01-01 00:01:01.600000+00:00  NaN
1970-01-01 00:01:02.300000+00:00  NaN
```

When you call `interpolate`, on that, it will fill in the `NaN` with the appropriate linear interpolation.

```
>>> data.resample('700l').mean().interpolate().head()
                                   v1
ts                                   
1970-01-01 00:00:59.500000+00:00  0.0
1970-01-01 00:01:00.200000+00:00  0.0
1970-01-01 00:01:00.900000+00:00  0.0
1970-01-01 00:01:01.600000+00:00  0.0
1970-01-01 00:01:02.300000+00:00  0.0
```

When you call `interpolate` directly on the output of `resample`, the behaviour of `interpolate` seems to be not as expected, giving a bunch of `NaN`s in the beginning, followed by a gradual slope from the max (1) down. Not really sure why:

```
>>> data.resample('700l').interpolate().head()
                                  v1
ts                                  
1970-01-01 00:00:59.500000+00:00 NaN
1970-01-01 00:01:00.200000+00:00 NaN
1970-01-01 00:01:00.900000+00:00 NaN
1970-01-01 00:01:01.600000+00:00 NaN
1970-01-01 00:01:02.300000+00:00 NaN
```

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing, in your answer, why it would give a different result without the `.mean()` part.

Comment: Because without the `mean`, it just tries to interpolate *all* the values, resulting in a gradual slope from the first point to the next valid point. with `mean`, it creates a bunch of `NaN` values, and the interpolation just occurs between the valid points (meaning it remains at `0` if the first point is `0` and the next point is `0`)

Comment: I'm at a loss. With or without the `mean`, the behaviour of `.interpolate(method='linear')` is strictly the same. It interpolates NaN values between two non-NaN values. My hunch here is that OP's confusion has to do with the fact that 60 (seconds) is prime with 7, but not with 6, and so different amount of NaNs are created.

Comment: @Jacquot, I agree that this should be the behavior of `.interpolate('linear')`, but it doesn't appear to be the case. See my update, it works with 700ms, 600ms and 1000ms (but only when calling a method before interpolate, doesn't necessarily need to be `mean`. I think it's just a thing with `resample`). To see the behavior of `.interpolate` without calling a method first, just try: `data.resample('700l').interpolate().head()`

Comment: Sacul, your work-around is working properly even though the first timestamp is always wrong (00:00:59.5 instead of 00:01:00). I will try to update pandas version to see if the problem will solve; otherwise I think I will floor my scantime to a smaller number, which is not prime with 60 (0.6 sec instead of 0.7 sec in this case).